# Different memtest results in different machines

Tags: memory, memtest

I have two old laptops: Dell Inspiron N5110 (Intel i5-2410M, 2x8GB Kingston 1600 DDR3) and HP Pavilion g6 (2x4GB same memory type). Recently on dell laptop I suspected bad ram because of checksum errors in BTRFS filesystem (for those who is not familiar - bad checksum errors in this fs are often caused by bad ram). I run memtest86+ v 5.01 on dell laptop (it has pre UEFI Bios firmware) - it revealed broken ram. I sent the ram to the servicing center, but they said they did not find any error.

Then I tested the suspected ram on other (hp) laptop via passmark memtest v8.02 (it has UEFI bios and I cannot run old memtest on it) - it also revealed approximately the same bad address. I bought a new ram and tested it on dell laptop - everything is ok. I cannot say that I tested every combination of RAM in my laptops, but broken ram was tested in both laptops at different slots with the same result (bad ram) while none of other memory sticks (in any combination) were detected as bad. I sent broken ram to the servicing center for the second time, but they again revealed no errors.

So my question is follows. Did I miss something in memory testing? I considered that if memory stick is detected as bad at two machines and other memory sticks are not, then there is 100% bad memory stick (bad cpu/ram controller/motherboard/memory slot are eliminated as possible reasons), but after results from servicing center I am not so quite sure.

Comment: What level of testing is this service centre running? Are they also running memtest but a less thorough set of tests? I would trust my own testing over a 3rd party.

Comment: It seems we have made at least 1 full pass. In the second time people from service center provided passmark screenshot which shows pass#1 was done and memtest was on midway in pass #2. I was also running memtest for one pass for good sticks of memory (but taking into account I was running several times in last weeks, effectively there are 1-2 passes for good sticks).